# UIButton tint color not working for whole button? Set in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have looked through other questions but can't find a definitive answer - I created my UIButton in my storyboard (not programmatically) and I am trying to tint the WHOLE button (not just text) on click. I have set my tint color to black and yet this does not affect the whole button.

I have tried setting my type to System as I heard that affects it but nothing has changed. Still no tint.

Furthermore I have to touch/click very "forcefully" (really press down if on device) to even trigger the tint color affecting the text on the button even though the button click registers.

The button's action func will be called so it does not affect functionality, but the text "highlighted state" seems to be only triggered if the user clicks really hard.

How can I tint the entire button? And why would the highlighted state only be triggered with really forced clicking?

Setting tint color -

[image]

Trying to implement with IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet var postBtn: UIButton!
postBtn = customButton()
        postBtn.highlightedColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

after creating custom class in new file:

```
public class customButton: UIButton {
    public var highlightedColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    public var unhighlightedColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    override public var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if (highlighted) {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            }
            else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I either get a bad access error if I declare postBtn initially as a `customButton()` or I am told postBtn has no member called highlightedColor. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show me screenshot how did you change the tint color?

Comment: didn't get your que clearly... Post some code...

Comment: @Sneha No i never set tint color in code just using storyboard

Comment: Have you tried by changing background color?

Comment: That just changes the unchecked color of the button. Is changing background color programmatically only wy to go?

Comment: Yes if you want to change color on button click event. Please Check my answer.

Answer (score 13):

> `tint` property sets the color of the button image and text.

As you don't have any image on your button, it only affect the color of the text

Also, `tint` will only affect the color of button's image when you set the button type to any except `custom`.

[image]

Now for example, we want to set the color of button image to red.

[image]

Then we will see:

[image]

In your case, you actually want to set the background color and title color of UIButton when button is highlighted.

For title color, you can directly use `button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Highlighted)`

For background color, there is no direct method you can use, but you can create a custom UIButton which override the `highlighted` property of UIButton or use `setBackgroundImage:forState:`

### Custom UIButton

```
public class customButton: UIButton {
    public var highlightedColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    public var unhighlightedColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    override public var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if (highlighted) {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            }
            else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let button1 = customButton()
let button2 = customButton()

button1.highlightedColor = UIColor.redColor()
button2.highlightedColor = UIColor.blueColor()
button1.unhighlightedColor = UIColor.clearColor()
button2.unhighlightedColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

### setBackgroundImage:forState:

Another method to achieve what you want is use `setBackgroundImage:forState:`. You may need to create an `UIImage` from `UIColor` first.

Generate a image from UIColor:

```
func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Usage:

```
button1.setBackgroundImage(getImageWithColor(UIColor.redColor(), size: button1.bounds.size), forState: .Highlighted)
button2.setBackgroundImage(getImageWithColor(UIColor.blueColor(), size: button2.bounds.size), forState: .Highlighted)
```

Comment: I have 3 different button colors.. how would you customize the color per button as this is an extension? I can't get the background color of the button and modify

Comment: See my updated answer, I provide two methods to achieve what you want.

Comment: Having trouble implementing your first method via an IBOutlet - I have updated my answer with what I've tried, Im getting errors. How would I implement this with buttons made in storyboard?

Comment: @skyguy Your outlet created in Storyboard also need to subclass to CustomButton. Change “IBOutlet var postBtn: UIButton!” to IBOutlet var postBtn: CustomButton!

Comment: I did that but am getting BAD_ACCESS error at runtime on the line in viewdidload where I set postBtn.highlightedColor = UIColor.blueColor()

Comment: and i changed my buttons to type custom in storyboard as well

Comment: @skyguy Try reconnecting your outlet. For more info about debugging bad access, this post will help http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

1) Set UIButton type to `custom` from storyboard

then write like below,

Create IBoutlet for that button like,

```
@IBOutlet var btnSubmit : UIButton!
```

Create click event of that button,

```
@IBAction func btnSubmitClick(sender : UIButton)
{
    if(sender.selected == false)
    {
        self.btnSubmit.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.btnSubmit.selected = true
    }
    else
    {
        self.btnSubmit.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.btnSubmit.selected = false
    }
}
```

This will change your whole button background color. Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

With regards your first question, you would need to do this in code. The tint only affects the text. If you wanted the background colour to change, you would need to change it manually as the button state changes. One way to do this would be to subclass UIButton and add a target/action on it for the relevant control events. In your case, you would listen to `UIControlEventTouchDown`to know when to change the background colour to your chosen 'highlight' colour, and `UIControlEventTouchDragExit`and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to know when to revert back to the normal state background colour.

Here's an existing implementation if you want to save time: https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyButton

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

For anyone doing it programatically:

```
var button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```